# Send 3 list from asynctask class to another class

Tags: java, android, list, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I am trying to send 3 list from a `AsyncTask` class to another. `AsyncTask` class takes 3 different datas from json and inserts 3 string list. I have to send this list to another class to insert recycler adapter.

```
public class FetchNewsData extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

static List<String> title = new ArrayList<>();
static List<String> body = new ArrayList<>();
static List<String> imageUrl = new ArrayList<>();

public List<String> getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public List<String> getBody() {
    return body;
}

public List<String> getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

private static String url = "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?format=json&show-fields=thumbnail,trailText&api-key=f627bebe-3c4f-4fee-a2fc-3368a3b098c7";
private static final String TAG_RESPONSE = "response";
private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "webTitle";
private static final String TAG_DATE = "webPublicationDate";
private static final String TAG_SECTION_NAME = "sectionName";
private static final String TAG_FIELDS = "fields";
private static final String TAG_TEXT = "trailText";
private static final String TAG_IMG_URL = "thumbnail";


@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    return json;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

    try {
        // Getting JSON Array
        JSONObject response = json.getJSONObject(TAG_RESPONSE);

        JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject resultsObjects = result.getJSONObject(i);

            JSONObject fields = resultsObjects.getJSONObject(TAG_FIELDS);


            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            if (resultsObjects.has(TAG_TITLE)) {
                String header = resultsObjects.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                title.add(header);
            } else title.add(null);

            if (fields.has(TAG_TEXT)) {
                String text = fields.getString(TAG_TEXT);
                body.add(text);
            } else body.add(null);

            if (fields.has(TAG_IMG_URL)) {
                String imgUrl = fields.getString(TAG_IMG_URL);
                imageUrl.add(imgUrl);
            } else imageUrl.add(null);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

In the following code the `RecyclerAdapter` should take that 3 list as parameter. How can I do this. Can someone help me please?

```
private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    List<String> itemList;
    itemList = createItemList();

    List<String> titleList=new ArrayList<>(itemData.getTitle());

    String[] itemlistToArray = new String[itemList.size()];
    itemlistToArray = itemList.toArray(itemlistToArray);

    String[] asd= {"a","b","c"};

    String[] titlelistToArray = new String[titleList.size()];
    titlelistToArray = titleList.toArray(titlelistToArray);

    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(asd, itemlistToArray, itemlistToArray);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
}
```

Comment: I would advice you to fully go through a [recyclerview](http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-recyclerview-tutorial/) tutorial and after that it will be easier

Comment: Thank you sir. It is very useful source. I am trying to use recyclerview with tabs. setupRecyclerView method is in my fragment class. Also I should get data from json and redirect data to adapter. I moved my setupRecyclerView  to FetchNewsData class. And I success the display text on textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you call your setupRecyclerView method directly from your onPostExecute method ??

If you do not want that you should store these list within a custom class and pass that class object through intent to other activity.

> 1) Create a custom class MyLists and set these lists within this class.
>
> 2) Implement this class with Serializable.
>
> 3) Pass Mylists
>   class object through intent to another activity.

Comment: Thank you sir. I moved my setupRecyclerView method to FetchNewsData class. And I success the display text on textview.

Comment: Happy coding :)